# ruby on rails - undefined method valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

im following ryan bates screen cast on how http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model on how to validate a form without a database

but i keep getting an undefined method valid?

heres my controller

```
def create
  @contacts = FreshDeskApiWrapper.new().post_tickets(params[:contacts])
  if @contacts.valid?
    redirect_to new_contact_path 
  else
   flash[:notice] = "OOps"
   render action: 'new'
 end
```

end

I can seem to call

```
 $ FreshDeskApiWrapper.new().valid?
```

just fine in the console but it does not seem to like it when i tack on the

```
 $ FreshDeskApiWrapper.new().post_tickets(params[email: 'user@example.com']).valid?
```

i get an undefined method valid?

There is something im not understanding about this

heres my fresh_desk_api_wrapper.rb file i created in my models folder

```
  class FreshDeskApiWrapper
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :config, :client, :subject, :email, :custom_field_phone_number_50754,      :custom_field_company_50754, :description
  validates :subject, presence: true   
  validates :email, presence: true  
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
    send("#{name}=", value)
  end
  self.config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/fresh_desk.yml")[Rails.env]
  self.client = Freshdesk.new(config[:url], config[:api_key], config[:password])
  end

  def post_tickets(params)
    client.post_tickets(params)
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

post_tickets is something im defining in there

Comment: what does it say that it is undefined for `i get an undefined method valid? `  , this an activerecord instance method , i am pretty sure the return type of `def post_tickets(params)
    client.post_tickets(params)
  end`  
is not aciverecord instance

Comment: Please show the *precise* error message and stack trace. Hint: `post_tickets` doesn't return anything with a `valid?` method.

Comment: @DaveNewton - heres the entire error message  undefined method `valid?' for #<String:0x007fd4ac3a2338>

Comment: @user1502223 Right, because `post_tickets` doesn't return anything with a `valid?` method. If you're trying to call `valid?` on an AR instance, you can't just tack it on to arbitrary methods that return other types (like a `String`).

Comment: @DaveNewton = ic thank you for the clearing that up....so i guess i need to find another way to validate this form?

Comment: ... No, you need to call valid? on the model

Answer (score 4):

You can call `valid?` on an single instance of an object, not multiple. `@contacts` would imply that your `post_tickets` method is returning multiple objects.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

@contacts = FreshDeskApiWrapper.new(post_tickets(params[:contacts])

what seems to be the problem is that the method you are adding dosnt return a active record object, so the method valid? is not available

Edit:

maybe this:

@contacts = FreshDeskApiWrapper.new(FreshDeskApiWrapper.post_tickets(params[:contacts])

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i tried what you said but got a undefined method `post_tickets' for #<Website::ContactsController:0x007fd4ac3691a0>

Answer (score 0):

omg im so dumb so what i did was

```
  def create

  @contacts = FreshDeskApiWrapper.new(params[:contacts])
  @contacts.post_tickets(params[:contacts])
  if @contacts.valid?
    redirect_to new_contact_path 
  else
   flash[:notice] = "OOps"
   render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

and it works!

Im still struggling to learn all this.....thanks for your guy's guidance it really helped